# Where to specify page/sort for my web grid (e.g. in controller or view)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gridview

Where should I initialize my web grid (and why, please, I'm seeking foresight rather than just opinions)?

On one hand, it seems logical to consider the current page number and sort order a "view concern", and from that perspective building a grid in the controller is uncomfortably similar to laying out HTML there.

On the other hand, it seems that page number for example is a "location concern", and it makes more sense to parse that directive in the controller.

From experience when the separation of responsibility isn't clear, there's a good chance I'll make a poor choice and end up with major refactoring later.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should make requests for a set of data, (page number, sort order...etc). Your controller acts on these request and presents the data to the view.

I would initialize your grid in the controller with a default view and sorting. On paging or sorting, the view would send parameters or a model to the controller. I like keeping as much logic in the controller as I can. It makes it easier to modify your view, create a mobile view, using ajax instead of a full page reload, etc.

There are also plenty of 3rd party grids available that support paging and sorting, have you considered this? However it is not difficult to roll your own.